# Diagnosing spike in 'direct traffic' in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

Recently ive seen a spike in the direct traffic in google analytics its up between 100-200% depending on what day you look at since last week.

I cant tell if this is just referral spam, which would be odd as theres nothing to click back to listed as the refer, but if there is a site thats sending hundreds of visitors our way (either maliciously or through a piece of content we are mentioned in) id like to know which site it is.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely **ghost spam**, lately the **spammers have been hitting with direct visits** along with the referral, probably as some kind of distraction.

If you have spam from one of the referrals ending with `-buttons.com`, then there is the problem. Here is an example:

[image]

This **account is inactive so all of it is spam**, 2 hits from referrals and 24 directs.

[image]

The usual way to stop it was creating a filter for the referral, but this **won't stop the direct visit**.

The best way to achieve this is by using a **Valid Hostname Filter**; this **will stop any ghost spam even if it is referral, direct or keyword**

You can find more information about this solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354319/3197362

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177813/3197362